# Find Big-Theta for the following program

Tags: algorithms, asymptotics

The algorithm is:

> sum $\gets 0$ 
>   for $i\gets 1$ to $n$ do 
>   $~~~~$ for $j \gets 1$ to $i^2$ do 
>   $~~~~~~~~~$ sum $\gets$ sum + ary$[i]$

If this was a big O problem I would say the loop is $O(n^4)$ because using the arithmetic sequence we can infer the nested for loop is $O\left(\frac{n^2(n^2+1)}{2}\right)$ but I'm not even sure about this. What's the difference when calculating Big Theta vs Big O?

Comment: Note that you do $i^2$ additions for each $i$ so there are only $\sum_{i=1}^n i^2 = \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6} \approx \frac{n^3}{3}$ operations involved. For your second question see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10376740/what-exactly-does-big-%D3%A8-notation-represent).

Answer (score 1):

$f(n)\in\Theta(g(n))$ iff $f(n)\in O(g(n))$ and $g(n)\in O(f(n))$. In other words, the two functions grow at the "same rate."

Since $$\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{i^{2}}1=n\left(n+1\right)\left(2n+1\right)/6\sim n^{3}/3,$$
it is indeed true that the runtime of the algorithm is in $O(n^3)$ (not $n^4$). But it is also true that the runtime of the algorithm is in $O(n^4)$, or $O(n!)$, etc..

However, can you say the same thing about $\Theta$?

Comment: Thanks, that snippet on Big-Theta vs Big-Oh was helpful. Can you tell me more about how you obtained the formula [n*(n+1)*(2n+1)]/6

Comment: Here's a trick: $\sum_{i=1}^{n}i^{2}\sim\int_{0}^{n}i^{2}dx\sim n^{3}/3$.

Comment: You can prove the sum formula by induction. For $n>0$: $\sum_{i=1}^{n}i^{2}=\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}i^{2}+n^{2}=\left(n-1\right) n \left(2n-1\right)/6+n^{2}=\ldots=n\left(n+1\right)\left(2n+1\right)/6$.